# HTML code inside of a R-markdown block for a single line

Tags: html, r, regex, knitr, r-markdown

I have an R-markdown document in a for loop (testing various kinds of models), and I would like to set them off with HTML Headers, as it is otherwise hard to find the models I am looking for. There is the `"asis"` option, but that turns off formatting for the entire block, which is not what I want. I have tried a few things I found here, but nothing really works. Here is my code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Mike Wise - 25 Jul 2014"
date: "November 2, 2015"
output: html_document
---

Test

```{r, echo=T}
for (i in 1:3){
  print("<h1>Title</h1>")
  #print("##Title")
  m <- data.frame(matrix(runif(25),5,5))
  print(m)
}
```
````

Here is one try that does not have the right title formatting:

[image]

And here is what it looks like with the `results="asis"` option:

[image]

Comment: why not use `kable(m, format = "html")` and keep the asis?

Comment: It is okay for tables, and something I considered, but in this application those things printered out are convergence messages for the different algorithms, i.e. not tables, and not the same for each iteration of the for loop. So that is not really an option.\

Comment: if you have convergence messages from model fit results you may want to have a look at broom::tidy to convert your model fit results into data.frames which then again could be displayed with kable.

Comment: Well, it is a lot of things, really. Convergence messages, summary, confusion matrix, all sorts of things that I might find useful for troubleshooting and/or picking between algorithms.I kind of wanted to keep it simple. But if there is no way to do what I asked, then I suppose I will have to go down that road.

Comment: if it's not a dataframe output, you could include an example of the outputs you do have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, it is a year and a half later and I still needed this from time to time, but I learned enough since then to know how to do it properly. You need to write a `knitr` "output hook", and modify the output so the html can "escape" through.

The following accomplishes this:

- Added a `knitr` output hook.
- Defined a syntax to specify the needed tag and content

  - for example to get `<h1>some_text</h1>` use `htmlesc<<(h1,some_text)>>`
- Figured out a regexp that extracts the `h1` and `some_text` and reformats it as properly tagged html, removing the `##` that `knitr` inserted as well.
- Added some more test cases to make sure it did some additional things (like `h4`, `p`, proper placement of plots and tables, etc.)
- Added another regexp to remove double escaped lines which was adding some unwanted whitespace paneled constructs.

So here is the code:

````
---
title: "Output Hook for HTML Escape"
author: "Someone"
date: "2017 M04 25"
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
---

```{r setup, include=T,echo=TRUE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
hook_output <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("output")


knitr::knit_hooks$set(output=function(x,options){
  xn <- hook_output(x,options)
  # interestingly xn is a big character string. 
  # I had expected a list or vector, but the length of x is 1 and the class is character.

  # The following regexp extracts the parameters from a statement of the form
  # htmlesc<<(pat1,pat2)>> and converts it to <pat1>pat2</pat1>
  xn <- gsub("## htmlesc<<([^,]*),{1}([^>>]*)>>","\n```\n<\\1>\\2</\\1>\n```\n",xn)
  # now remove double escaped lines that occur when we do these right after each other
  gsub(">\n```\n\n\n```\n<",">\n<",xn)
}
)
```

## An analysis loop in a single R chunk with R Markdown

In the following, we do a loop and generate 3 sets of data:

(@) We have some explanitory text
(@) then we do a bar plot with ggplot
(@) then we print out a table
(@) then we do a base plot - just for fun

```{r, echo=T, fig.height=3,fig.width=5}
library(knitr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)

for (i in 1:3){
  mdf <- data.frame(matrix(runif(25),5,5))
  cat(sprintf("htmlesc<<h1,Title %d>>\n",i))
  cat(sprintf("htmlesc<<h4,Smaller Title - also for %d>>\n",i))
  cat(sprintf("htmlesc<<p,and some text talking about this %d example>>\n",i))
  print(sapply(mdf,mean))
  gdf <- gather(mdf,series,val)
  gp <- ggplot(gdf)+geom_bar(aes(series,val,fill=series,color=I("black")),stat="identity")
  print(gp)
  print(mdf)
  plot(mdf)
}
```
````

And this is the output (shrunk a bit as you don't need the details).

[image]

The only real docs for this by the way are Yihui's excellent knitr book, a search finds it easily.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `kable` function:

````
```{r, echo=T, results="asis"}
library(knitr)
for (i in 1:3){
  print("<h1>Title</h1>")
  #print("##Title")
  m <- data.frame(matrix(runif(25),5,5))
  print(kable(m, format = "html"))
}
```
````

Which gives me:

[image]

Comment: See my comment above. It is not really about tables, it is about various kinds of output in the for loop. This is just a toy sample. So Kable is not really the way forward. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

````
```{r, echo=F, results="asis"}
for (i in 1:3){
  library(knitr)
  print("<h1>Title</h1>")
  #print("##Title")
  m1 <- knitr::kable(data.frame(matrix(runif(25),5,5)))
  print(m1)
}
````

```

Comment: Same as suggested above by jeremycg. Has the same issue. I need it to work for general output, not just kable.