# How do we use HTML inside ```r

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a generated a document in RMD file. Out side `r, I can use html tags as shown below. But inside`r, Can we use html tags. For example, I need Welcome to be used using html tags inside ```r. Is it possible?

````
<i>Welcome:</i>

```r{}
print()
```
````

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478874/html-code-inside-of-a-r-markdown-block-for-a-single-line

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be

````
<i>Welcome:</i>

```r{}
text = "Hello &copy;<b>bold</b>"
```

`r text`
````