# Can we use HTML features in TinyTex (R Markdown)

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, tinytext

everyone!
I'm VERY new to Rmarkdown, so this may be a silly question. I was able to use HTML tags when kniting html file. However, I'm wondering If I could also use them when kniting a pdf file? I'm a bit used to HTML, so it would really help me if I could keep on with the HTML tags for my pdf reports as well. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60719241/how-do-we-use-html-inside-r) helped me a bit, but not quite.

For Example, when kniting a html file it works just fine, I'd like to use the same labels with TinyTex...is it possible?

[image: My code in HTMl]

Thanks in advance

Maybe [these packages](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html-widgets.html) and [this IF](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/font-color.html) may be useful, but, I still cannot use the proper html labels..

Comment: I will not be so demanding to expect that some process will translate any html to latex:)

Comment: @ZheyuanLi , there's an "if" solution here [https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/font-color.html] , but, still, I didn't manage to use raw html

Comment: This may be helpful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57548218/2425163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use HTML in the Markdown document and then render it directly to PDF.
However you could render the document to html and later covert it to pdf manually from browser print method or automatically e.g. with ‘pagedown::chrome_print’ package.

When the rmarkdown output is a pdf_output then a markdown is translated to latex and then rendered to pdf. There is no process to translate a part of the text from html to what … sth understandable and similar in latex.

Comment: Yes you could ensure it:)

Comment: Simply use \newpage in the markdown doc, works for any output type. Please use the backslash.

Comment: @polkas , I'm sorry, but where exactly should I add \newpage?

Comment: My comments looks strange now when somebody (we know who) ones are removed. Add \newpage in the markdown text where ever you want to split the text (separate pages). For html document it is not influence anything till e.g. as I suggested you will generated a pdf from browser printing panel. These comments were regarding a pagination connected to my answer.