# Render ggplot2 plot in HTML template within RMarkdown

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr

I've built a function in rmarkdown to produce some HTML output with given values, but I want it to work if one of the passed values references a ggplot object.

Basically, knitr renders this perfectly:

````
x <- [R computation]
y <- [ggplot figure]

<div id="some_number">`r x`</div>
<div id="some_figure">
```{r}
y
```
</div>
````

But I don't want to have to rewrite that every time I use that particular chunk of html with different `x` and `y`. So I wrote the following function:

```
html_func <- function(x,y) {

    template <- "
<div id=\"some_num\">{x}</div>
<div id=\"some_fig\">{y}</div>
    "

    instance <- glue::glue(template)
    output <- knitr::asis_output(instance)

    return(output)
}

number <- [R computation]
figure <- [ggplot figure]

html_func(number, figure)
```

The rendered page shows the "number" computed correctly within the div, but doesn't render the plot.

**How can I get it to produce the plot within the HTML container?**

**UPDATE:** Commenter suggested using live data so here we go.

This works:

````
```{r}
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

number <- mean(mtcars$mpg)
figure <- ggplot2::ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) + 
    geom_point()
```
<div id="some_number">`r number`</div>
<div id="some_figure">
```{r echo=FALSE}
figure
```
</div>
````

But this does not. The computation outputs fine, but the plot does not render.

````
```{r}
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

number <- mean(mtcars$mpg)
figure <- ggplot2::ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg)) + 
    geom_point()

html_func <- function(x,y) {

    template <- "
<div id=\"some_num\">{x}</div>
<div id=\"some_fig\">{y}</div>
        "

    instance <- glue::glue(template)
    output <- knitr::asis_output(instance)

    return(output)
}

html_func(number, figure)
```
````

Here's a screenshot comparing the two.

[image: Difference in html rendering]

Comment: Hopefully it's clear in the example that the text in [] are just placeholders for arbitrary content, not actual syntax.

Comment: I can't get your function to work (maybe show some actual objects that allow it to work for you?) but I'm wondering if you need an explicit `print()` for the plot. That would be necessary in a `results = "asis"` style chunk, anyway.

Comment: Thank you @aosmith. I've updated the post to correct a small error that might have caused problems, replicated the issue with data, and shown my outputs.

Comment: You can get the plot by using `print(figure)` instead of just `figure` but it appears you also still get the printed object. Are you attached to `knitr::asis_output()` or would you consider using a `results = "asis"` chunk? I've never used one for writing HTML with R output, though, only markdown, so maybe that's a problem.

Comment: So as you noted, `print(figure)` produced the plot, but not rendered within the HTML container, and the printed object still appears.

I'm not married to `knitr::asis_output()` but doing `{r results="asis"]` produces the same thing.

Comment: I wonder if [this sort of old solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43601964/2461552) showing an output hook will help? It refers back to the **knitr** book, so could be some good info there (I haven't looked :D).

Answer (score 0):

So this is a **BAD** solution.

````
```{r}
html_func_open <- function(x) {

    template <- "
<div id=\"some_num\">{x}</div>
<div id=\"some_fig\">
    "

    instance <- glue::glue(template)
    output <- knitr::asis_output(instance)

    return(output)
}

html_func_close <- function() {
      template <- "
</div>
    "

    instance <- glue::glue(template)
    output <- knitr::asis_output(instance)

    return(output)
}

html_func_open(number)
figure
html_func_close()
```
````

I get the output I want by doing the plot outside of the HTML template, then closing up the HTML in a second function. This allows the HTML on either side of the figure to be as complex as I want. But it's not really an ideal solution, since It requires multiple lines every time I want to add in a new figure, which limits the complexity with which I can build HTML containers.

So still seeking a better solution where I can just pass the figure to the function and have it render properly.